# Jquery flex slider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

For some reason the nav buttons are being cut off instead of sittin ontop of the slider here is a screen shot [screenshot of nav buttons cut off](http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/screenshot.jpg) Ive tried all sorts and can't get it to work am I missing something

Comment: Have you got a link to the code? It's very hard to debug an issue without the code to reference =)

Comment: its not live so ill give you code in text files here is html [link]http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/flexhtml.txt

Comment: here is jquery [link]http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/flexjquery.txt

Comment: here is css [link]http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/slidercss.txt

Comment: @TomDickinson was this helpful

Comment: @Chandu vkm do you know why this is happening in flex slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know I solved the problem. I hadn't set the flex-container up correctly. After scanning the code with fresh eyes I saw the mistake.

Comment: Glad you did it! It would be good that you post 'How I resolved it:' Otherwise nor the Q and the A are useful.